# Console App exits abruptly when calling async methods in Debug

Tags: c#, async-await, task, visual-studio-2022

It happens on Console and Windows Service apps, haven't tested on Windows Forms or WPF. When stepping thru the code whenever it hits an `async` call with await, the debug session exits abruptly, can't go further. As a workaround I'm using `Task.Run()` but changing all the `async` calls to use `Task.Run()` syntax during debug, and put it back to `await` syntax for deployment is a hassle.

Here in this method below, the following line is the issue during Debug, it works as expected when deployed.

```
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

Work around while debugging is to change the above line to this:

```
//var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
var task = Task.Run(() => httpClient.SendAsync(request));
task.Wait();
var response = task.Result;
```

Code:

```
private static async Task<string> SendRequest()
{
    string result = "";
    string url = "http://localhost:5119/WeatherForecast";
    var URL = new Uri(url);
    var method = new HttpMethod("GET");
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, URL))
    {
        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

        //var task = Task.Run(() => httpClient.SendAsync(request));
        //task.Wait();
        //var response = task.Result;
        result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried surrounding the method with a try catch to see if it catches anything in debug?

Comment: Actually, have you checked the whole "stack" of calls? I've had this problem when I missed an await on an async method, because some call did not wait for the method completion.

Comment: Have you checked Content has a value before reading it?

Comment: You probably just need to change `void Main` to `async Task Main` and use `await`.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar issue in a .NET 7 Console application.

I had already changed my App.Run method to be async, but I was not awaiting it.  My issue was resolved by adding the "await" on this line in Program.cs:

```
await services.GetRequiredService<App>().Run(args);
```

I would have caught this earlier if I was paying attention to my warnings.  For anyone wrestling with a similar issue just check the warnings and make sure your using async/await all the way up and down the call stack.